# JSON.parse not able to parse (Unexpected Token)

Tags: ruby, cucumber

JSON.parse returns back error:

```
# Ruby code in IRB
require 'json'
time_now = t.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
hash = '"date":' + time_now.to_s
hash_json = JSON.parse(hash)
```

Error:

> JSON::ParserError: 743: unexpected token at 'Sun, 14 May 2017 21:19:02 GMT'

My need is to have a JSON hash that has a Key/Value as:

```
# JSON hash
"date": "Sun, 14 May 2017 21:19:02 GMT"
```

Any insight ? I've tried this in a few ways, but running into same issue each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hash needs to be defined like this: `hash = {"date" => time_now}`.

In addition, `JSON.parse` returns a hash from a JSON formatted string. Hash has a method `to_json` which does the opposite:

```
require 'json'
time_now = Time.now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
hash = {'date' => time_now}
hash_json = hash.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the hash correctly. This is incorrect:

```
hash = {'"date":' + time_now}
```

It should be:

```
hash = {'date' => time_now}
```

Answer (score -1):

Json parsing when you can use , data contain json structure ;
so , hash = '"date":' + time_now.to_s problem here

```
hash = {"date"=> time_now.to_s}
```

Comment: irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
    => true
    irb(main):002:0> t= Time.now
    => 2017-05-14 23:02:57 -0400
    irb(main):003:0> time_now = t.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
    => "Sun, 14 May 2017 23:02:57 GMT"
    irb(main):004:0> hash = {'"date":' + time_now}
    SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
hash = {'"date":' + time_now}
                             ^